# Is there a way to have a file path in T-sql and PostgreSQL that stays within the project directory?

Tags: sql, postgresql, t-sql, variables, filepath

I am importing data from a CSV file using the COPY FROM in PostgreSQL. It works flawlessly on my machine, however, were I to clone the repository onto a new machine the code would cease to function to the file path being hardcoded starting at the Users directory of the computer.

In other languages, I would be able to use something like ./ or ~/ to start somewhere not at the absolute beginning of the file, but I haven't found T-SQL or Postgres to have that functionality available.

What I have

```
COPY persons(name,address,email,phone)
FROM '/Users/admin/Development/practice/data/persons.csv
```

How can I make that file path function on any machine the project gets cloned to?

Comment: T-SQL is the dialect of SQL supported by SQL Server and Sybase, but this question seems to be entirely about PostgreSQL, so... what gives?

Comment: If I miscategorized it I am very sorry. Today is the first day that I am writing sql code. I don't mean to mislead.

Comment: where is this SQL stored at?  in a SPROC? or in a sql file somewhere?

Comment: So, **do** you need a solution that works on PostgreSQL **and** Microsoft SQL Server?